# PlayerIndex and PlayerIndex?

Tags: c#, input, xna

I have a question about PlayerIndex and how to use it.

The problem is the second controller (controllingPlayer2) need to be "null" sometimes (for one player Mode, for example) but the GetState cannot accept a null variable.

I have a class (for my gamescreen) like this:

```
    public GameScreen(PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer, PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer2)
    {
        this.ControllingPlayer = controllingPlayer;
        this.ControllingPlayer2 = controllingPlayer2;
    }

    public override void HandleInput()
    {
        // Move the character UP - Problem appears at the GetState Here wanting a PlayerIndex not a null?
        if (GamePad.GetState(ControllingPlayer).IsButtonDown(controls.BUp))
        {
            P1movementY--;
        }

        // Move the second character UP - Problem appears at the GetState Here wanting a PlayerIndex not a null?

        if (GamePad.GetState(ControllingPlayer).IsButtonDown(controls.BUp))
        {
            P2movementY--;
        }
```

Comment: Can you use GamePad.GetState() to see if the controller is actually plugged in first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, you can look up how Nullable works [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

```
public override void HandleInput()
{
    if (ControllingPlayer.HasValue && GamePad.GetState(ControllingPlayer.Value).IsButtonDown(controls.BUp))
    {
        P1movementY--;
    }

    if (ControllingPlayer2.HasValue && GamePad.GetState(ControllingPlayer2.Value).IsButtonDown(controls.BUp))
    {
        P2movementY--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use with && to short circuit if blocks early

```
    if (ControllingPlayer2 != null && GamePad.GetState(ControllingPlayer2).IsButtonDown(controls.BUp))
    {
        P2movementY--;
    }
```

Comment: C# will complain about that syntax... You can't do an implicit null check like in C, and there's still the problem of passing a PlayerIndex? to a method that expects a PlayerIndex.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, check if (ControllingPlayer != null) and then use ControllingPlayer.Value.

Longer form,
The question mark syntax in C# allows you to pass a value type, for which null is not an assignable value, as null.  It's shorthand for Nullable< PlayerIndex >, which has a couple properties like HasValue:bool and Value:PlayerIndex.  It's not really the same as the non-Nullable version of the type.